# How to fit the child div inside parent and scroll the overflow text only in the Y axis

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to have my child `div` inside the parent `div` fitting the `height` and `width` of the child `div` to the space that has left inside its parent.

Furthermore, I'd like to scroll just the child `div` in the `Y axis`. I used the `overflow-y:auto` to achieve this, however it's scrolling both in X and Y axis. (See snippet below).

```css
#Parent {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}
#Parent > #Child {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
  <h6>Help Me</h6>
  <div id="Child">
    <p>
      dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `box-sizing:border-box` to fit the `width`/`height`

Then the horizontal bar is caused by not having spaces between words, so eiher

- change `overflow-y:auto` for `overflow-x:hidden`

or if you are planning in having texts without spaces (which seems unlikely)

- use `word-wrap: break-word` or `word-break: break-all`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#Parent {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}
#Parent > #Child {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
  <div id="Child">
    <p>
      dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this style to cause the text to wrap even though there are no spaces:

```
#Parent > #Child {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```css
#Parent {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}
#Parent > #Child {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-y: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
  <h6>Help Me</h6>
  <div id="Child">
    <p>
      dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>dsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasdadsadasdasdasda
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to insert a few spaces into the placeholder text. The problem is the browser won't insert line breaks, it makes the child div wider instead. But it won't be a problem with real text which consists of words, separated by spaces.

EDIT: You can also consider @Rick Hitchcock's answer.